# Very basic Appear and dissapear text (Almost done)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone explain me why the first works and the other doesn't ? I need to blink a text inside a table td

Any help?

```js
var blink = angular.module('blink', [])
.directive('blink', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            function showElement() {
                $element.css("display", "inline");
                $timeout(hideElement, 1000);
            }

            function hideElement() {
                $element.css("display", "none");
                $timeout(showElement, 1000);
            }
            showElement();
        },
        template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="blink">
<blink><b>Works</b></blink>
</div>

<div ng-app="blink">
<blink><b>Doesn't. WHY?</b></blink>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to initialise `ng-app` only once. Make sure that both directives are wrapped in it. If you initialise it twice, you will have angular bootstrap issues

Comment: blink in 2018?? According to the docs: This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Comment: your code will work if you remove second initialise ng-app.

Comment: Use `marquee` instead.

Comment: Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first `ngApp` found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using `angular.bootstrap` instead.

Answer (score 0):

ng-app is twice, add only 1 element with the ng-app directive

```js
var blink = angular.module('blink', [])
  .directive('blink', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: function($scope, $element) {
        function showElement() {
          $element.css("display", "inline");
          $timeout(hideElement, 1000);
        }

        function hideElement() {
          $element.css("display", "none");
          $timeout(showElement, 1000);
        }
        showElement();
      },
      template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
      replace: true
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="blink">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <blink><b>Works</b></blink>
      </td>
      <td>
        <blink><b>Doesn't. WHY?</b></blink>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I NEED IN A TD!!

Comment: Done, please approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

Voila, you have duplicated ng-app="blink"

```js
var blink = angular.module('blink', [])
.directive('blink', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            function showElement() {
                $element.css("display", "inline");
                $timeout(hideElement, 1000);
            }

            function hideElement() {
                $element.css("display", "none");
                $timeout(showElement, 1000);
            }
            showElement();
        },
        template: '<td><span ng-transclude></span></td>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="blink">
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
   <blink><b>Works</b></blink>
   <blink><b>Doesn't. WHY?</b></blink>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```